# tf.gather_nd seems to be problematic when used in a Keras model ( '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int' )

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Trying to run this model

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

from tensorflow.keras.models import Model 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Reshape 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Convolution2D 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPooling2D 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten


inputs = Input(shape=(80,80,8), name="images" )

conv_1 = Convolution2D(32, (5, 5), padding="same", activation='relu')(inputs) conv_1 = MaxPooling2D(strides=(2,2))(conv_1)

conv_2 = Convolution2D(64, (5, 5), padding="same", activation='relu')(conv_1) conv_2 = MaxPooling2D(strides=(2,2))(conv_1) conv_2_flat = Flatten()(conv_2)

dense_1 = Dense(512, activation='relu')(conv_2_flat) 
y_pred = Dense(3, name='prediction')(dense_1) 
act = tf.math.argmax(y_pred, 1)

enum_action = Input(shape=(2), dtype=tf.int32, name="enum_act") 
gathered_layer = tf.gather_nd(y_pred, enum_action)

model = Model(inputs=[inputs,enum_action], outputs=gathered_layer) 
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='mean_squared_error',metrics=['accuracy'])

image = np.arange(0, 80*80*8)
enum = np.array([[0,0]])
image = image.reshape(1, 80,80,8) 
y_true = np.array([[12]]) 

model .fit([image,enum], y_true)
```

But I keep getting this error message

'>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

Any ideas what could be wrong with my model?

Comment: is `y_pred` `None` by any chance?

Comment: it shouldn't be, it's the layer after dense_1, so should have a value out, I tried running predict rather fit on the model, and everything seems fine, it's just when tryna fit the model it fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try in this way

```
inputs = Input(shape=(80,80,8), name="images" )

conv_1 = Convolution2D(32, (5, 5), padding="same", activation='relu')(inputs) 
conv_1 = MaxPooling2D(strides=(2,2))(conv_1)

conv_2 = Convolution2D(64, (5, 5), padding="same", activation='relu')(conv_1) 
conv_2 = MaxPooling2D(strides=(2,2))(conv_1) 
conv_2_flat = Flatten()(conv_2)

dense_1 = Dense(512, activation='relu')(conv_2_flat) 
y_pred = Dense(3, name='prediction')(dense_1) 

enum_action = Input(shape=(2), dtype=tf.int32, name="enum_act") 
gathered_layer = Lambda(lambda x: tf.expand_dims(tf.gather_nd(x[0],x[1]),-1))([y_pred, enum_action])

model = Model(inputs=[inputs,enum_action], outputs=gathered_layer) 
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

image = np.arange(0, 80*80*8)
enum = np.array([[0,0]])
image = image.reshape(1, 80,80,8) 
y_true = np.array([[0]]) 

model.fit([image,enum], y_true)
```